# I have a strange issue with Paypal adaptive API

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a strange problem with paypal

I'm trying to use Paypal adaptive API payment but is doing a strange problem

the status of de APPID is Approved Automatically.

Parameters say at once that there is a mistake and pay key created that works.

```
PAYPAL RETURN PARAMETERS: 
[Ack] => Failure
[ErrorID] => 550001
[Message] => User is not allowed to perform this action 
[Parameter] => EmailMarketing
[Severity] => Error 
[Subdomain] => Application

AND 

[PayKey] =>  GOOD-WORKING-PAY-KEY
[PaymentExecStatus] => CREATED
[RedirectURL] => RedirectURL
```

I tested de RedirectURL and works

If i put the RedirectURL directly in browser it works and creates the paypal form to pay

I do not know what to do to solve the error ?¿???¿?

Thanks in advance.

DELETED SECOND EDITION NOT NEEDED FOR RESPONSE

Comment: There must be some feature you're trying to use that your App ID isn't approved for.  You're saying you're getting a Failure for Ack but then you also get a good paykey..??  That is odd.  Can you provide a sample of your raw API request?

Comment: Hi thanks Andrew for replay. I edited the question with a raw response with a working pay key. If you put the redirectUrl in the browser it works. But i liked to solve the ack failure. I am working with your very good paypal adaptive library in php ;)

Comment: I was asking to see the raw request, not the response.  Since you're working with my class library it may make sense for you to [submit a ticket here](https://www.angelleye.com/support) and I can help you more directly.

Comment: Sorry ^_^ I edited with the raw request data. Maybe is a simple error in request data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer ^_^

I do not know why exactly, but with this parameters in request :

```
EmailHeaderImageURL = NULL 
EmailMarketingImageURL = NULL
```

is working

1) maybe is caracter not allowed in the name of the url

2) maybe not correctly configured in paypal in some place

i will continue searching

this error is indicated in paypal with

```
[Ack] => Failure
[ErrorID] => 550001
[Message] => User is not allowed to perform this action 
[Parameter] => EmailMarketing
```

And is odd but creates a working PAY KEY , maybe paypal "thinks" that this error is not too bad for not create the PAY KEY or maybe a paypal error.

Answer (score 0):

For such "User is not allowed to perform this action" error message, it usually due to APP id is not fully approved. I strongly suggest you to open a ticket at http://www.paypal-techsupport.com/, ask PayPal to check your APP Id status , make sure it's fully approved.

Comment: Hi thanks for replay. I really do not know if it is fully approved, but the status of de APPID is Approved Automatically. I think that this is approved.